# How can make my router (AltoRouter) work with my controllers on a PHP app

Tags: php, model-view-controller, router, altorouter

I would like to know how make my controllers be queried before sending back the view.
More simply, I would like to make my router work with the MVC architecture.
Currenly, i managed to configure my routes and send the user to the views with the AltoRouter library and without controller. 
**Index.php**

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/altorouter/altorouter/AltoRouter.php';
$router = new AltoRouter();

// map homepage
$router->map('GET', '/', function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/home.php';
});

$router->map('GET', '/error404', function () {
    require __DIR__ . '/views/error404.php';
});

// match current request url
$match = $router->match();

// call closure or throw 404 status
if (is_array($match) && is_callable($match['target'])) {
    call_user_func_array($match['target'], $match['params']);
} else {
// no route was matched
    header('location: /error404');
}
```

**Htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Controller

```php
<?php
require 'Models/Home.php'
class homeController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->main();
    }

    public function main()
    {
        $_model = new Home();
    }
}
$controler = new homeController()
```

Comment: I’m unclear what your question is. Are you looking for the `controller#action` syntax that’s in the [documentation](https://altorouter.com/usage/mapping-routes.html)? You might want to look into using the full autoload syntax of Composer/PHP, not just loading individual files.

Comment: My router must redirect to my controllers, right ? 
Then my controller sends the view back ?
Or i didn't understand the purpose of a router and relation with controllers

Comment: in your project are you using RouteDispatcher ?

Comment: No why ? My problem will be solved with RouteDispatcher ?

Comment: In your router you define _routes_ which are combinations of HTTP methods and URL patterns, along with the code to execute if a request comes in matching those. That code and execution is completely up to you (when using this specific router). MVC is a high level concept for thinking about how to map conceptual things to code, however it is also just an opinion, and I personally think you shouldn’t get too hung up on it. Separation of concerns where each part does one thing is great, but at the end of the day code just needs to run.